# Visual Studio Code LaTeX date time

Tags: datetime, times, visual-studio-code

I am using visual studio code LaTeX workshop. Here is my code :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[yyyymmdd,hhmmss]{datetime}

\title{my title}
\author{author}
\date{Compiled at: \today-\currenttime}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Some content

\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

However, the time is not correct because on my computer it is only January 4th 20:00 (I am at Montréal). It is off by several hours. I know that this is because the time zone is incorrect. On overleaf, I remember I can create a file `latexmkrc` with line `$ENV{'TZ'}='America/Toronto';` to resolve this. But this does not work for visual studio code .

Comment: The `datetime` package has been obsolete for a while now, replaced by [`datetime2`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2). Give a try to this one, and give additional details about your configuration if it doesn't work.